# Show span below text box

Tags: css, rendering, html

In the below code my span is showed at the right side of  the text box I want it below the text box. Please let me know what can be done?

```
<fieldset class="no_border">
    <div class="float_left">
        <label>Age in years:</label>
        <br />
        <input readonly="readonly" type="text" class="effect" id="nominee_one_years" name="nominee_one_years" value="0" style="width:20%" /><span id="info_nominee_one_years">x</span>
    </div>
    <div class="float_left">
        <label>Relationship:</label>
        <br />
        <input type="text" class="effect" name="nominee_one_relationship" id="nominee_one_relationship" style="width:95%" /><span id="info_nominee_one_relationship">x</span>
    </div>
    <div class="float_left">
        <label>Relationship:</label>
        <br />
        <input type="text" class="effect" name="nominee_one_relationship" id="nominee_one_relationship" style="width:95%" /><span id="info_nominee_one_relationship">x</span>
    </div>



#nominee_details span {
     margin-left: 0px;
     color: #b1b1b1;
     font-size: 11px;
     font-style: italic;
     display:none;
 }
 fieldset.no_border {
     overflow:hidden;
     border:0;
     padding:0 0 10px 0;
     margin:0;
 }
 .float_left {
     float:left;
     width:33%;
 }
```

other spans without DIV

```
<fieldset class="no_border">

        <label>Age in years:</label>
        <br />
        <input readonly="readonly" type="text" class="effect" id="nominee_one_years" name="nominee_one_years" value="0" style="width:20%" /><span id="info_nominee_one_years">x</span>
</fieldset >
```

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fakhruddin/vNaSZ/)

I actually have 2 situation

1st where  are inside fieldset and div as shown above and
2nd where  are inside fieldset

span for 1st case are not getting rendered below text box 
span for second are displayed properly

if you see my jsfiddle you shall understand what i am trying to explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/dwWww/5/

Are you looking for this?

```
.float_left span {
    display: block;
}
```

If you can use jquery, First you set `display: none;`

```
$(".float_left span").css("display","none");
```

But when you detect an error just do:

```
$(".float_left span").css("display","block");
```

Or just:

[**.addClass()**](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) //set display block

[**.removeClass**()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) //set display none

Or:

```
$(".float_left span").text("Error!!");
```

and

```
$(".float_left span").text('');
```

---

**Update:**

```
.float_left span, #nominee_details span  {
    display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M8XQ6/

Comment: thanks but i want display none originally and on invalid input it would be display block

Comment: tell me if i write `.float_left span {
    display: block;
}` will the text display below text box

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala, yes.

Comment: no its still coming on right side and I have cross checked the css class is getting applied to the span

Comment: see the demo. all Spans are below the inputs

Comment: yes was looking that let me figure out where am i going wrong

Comment: i have a form `<form id="nominee_details" name="nominee_details" action="">` when i type `#nominee_details .float_left span { display: block; }` its not working

Comment: actually I have other span outside divs too so the above class would be by default get applied to all spans

Comment: I have updated the question adding that piece of code too as an example code. Span are working fine with those part

Comment: just use: 
 `.float_left span, #info_nominee_one_years { display: block;}` 
 if you want to apply the same style or the invert if you want to exclude all span with a specific id
 `.float_left span, span:not(#info_nominee_one_years) { display: block;}`

Comment: sorry but I am unable to get it may be I am too much frustrated see if you can correct the jsfiddle added by me

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala please edit your question with a description of what you want. I am totally confused.

Comment: thanks dude got it finally...it ws altogether a different bug though...but got it sorted...thanks for your time and effort..

Answer (score 0):

`span` is an inline element, you may want to use a block level element like `div` or `p` or set `display:block` to the span or put a `<br/>` just before the span.

Comment: This should be a comment, surely.